# unable to form structure and filter out the values based on flag by iterating items data

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to form the structure like expectedOutput by iterating items data and filter out the data when flag is true and original items should remain as it is but need to create new array instead of modifying the existing array

```js
let items = [
  {tab:'tab1',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'alm' ,flag:true },{mnemonic:'second',value:'jim' ,flag:true }]},
  {tab:'tab2',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'kim' ,flag:false},{mnemonic:'second',value:'tim' ,flag:false}]},
  {tab:'tab3',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'wint',flag:true },{mnemonic:'second',value:'telt',flag:false}]
}];

let expectedOutput = [
  {tab:'tab1',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'alm' ,flag:true },{mnemonic:'second',value:'jim' ,flag:true }]},
  {tab:'tab3',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'wint',flag:true }]}
];

const getChecked = () => {
  const res = items.filter((item) => {
    if(item.tab.length>0) {
      item.info.filter((_eachItem)=>_eachItem.flag==true);
    }
    return item;
  })
  return res;
}

const arr = getChecked();
console.log('newArr',arr);
console.log('-items', items);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `.map` each item to change its `info` property so as to include only truthy `flag` values, then `.filter` the items to include only items which have at least one item in the resulting `info` array:

```js
let items = [{tab:'tab1',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'alm',flag:true},{mnemonic:'second',value:'jim',flag:true}]},
             {tab: 'tab2',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'kim',flag:false},{mnemonic:'second',value:'tim',flag:false}]},
             {tab:'tab3',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'wint',flag:true},
                               {mnemonic:'second',value:'telt',flag:false}]
             }]

let expectedOutput = [{tab:'tab1',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'alm',flag:true},{mnemonic:'second',value:'jim',flag:true}]},
             {tab:'tab3',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'wint',flag:true}]
             }]

const getChecked = () => items
  .map(
     ({ info, ...rest }) => ({ ...rest, info: info.filter(
       ({ flag }) => flag
     ) })
   )
   .filter(
     item => item.info.length
   );

const arr = getChecked();
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr) === JSON.stringify(expectedOutput));
```

To also remove the `mnemonic` property, `.map` the info to remove the property:

```js
let items = [{tab:'tab1',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'alm',flag:true},{mnemonic:'second',value:'jim',flag:true}]},
             {tab: 'tab2',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'kim',flag:false},{mnemonic:'second',value:'tim',flag:false}]},
             {tab:'tab3',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'wint',flag:true},
                               {mnemonic:'second',value:'telt',flag:false}]
             }]

let expectedOutput = [{tab:'tab1',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'alm',flag:true},{mnemonic:'second',value:'jim',flag:true}]},
             {tab:'tab3',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'wint',flag:true}]
             }]

const getChecked = () => items
  .map(
     ({ info, ...rest }) => ({
       ...rest,
       info: info
         .filter(({ flag }) => flag)
         .map(({ mnemonic, ...rest }) => rest)
     })
   )
   .filter(
     item => item.info.length
   );

const arr = getChecked();
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: suppose, if i dont want to have mnemonic field ie, may i know where can i add that check,let expectedOutput = [{tab:'tab1',info:[{value:'alm',flag:true},{value:'jim',flag:true}]},
             {tab:'tab3',info:[{value:'wint',flag:true}]
             }]

Comment: You'll need another `.map`, see snippet

Comment: @chidananda In TS, you can destructure into a different variable name which starts with a `_` to indicate that it's deliberate. `.map(({ mnemonic: _, ...rest }) => rest)`

Answer (score 0):

First you `map` the `items`, with each iterated item, filter its `info`, get the ones that has `flag` of `true`. After that, `filter` the result array which has `item.info` array of not empty

```
const newItems = items
  .map((item) => ({
    ...item,
    info: item.info.filter((itemInfo) => itemInfo.flag === true),
  }))
  .filter((item) => item.info.length > 0)
```

**Full demo**

```js
let items = [
  {
    tab: "tab1",
    info: [
      { mnemonic: "first", value: "alm", flag: true },
      { mnemonic: "second", value: "jim", flag: true },
    ],
  },
  {
    tab: "tab2",
    info: [
      { mnemonic: "first", value: "kim", flag: false },
      { mnemonic: "second", value: "tim", flag: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    tab: "tab3",
    info: [
      { mnemonic: "first", value: "wint", flag: true },
      { mnemonic: "second", value: "telt", flag: false },
    ],
  },
]

let expectedOutput = [
  {
    tab: "tab1",
    info: [
      { mnemonic: "first", value: "alm", flag: true },
      { mnemonic: "second", value: "jim", flag: true },
    ],
  },
  { tab: "tab3", info: [{ mnemonic: "first", value: "wint", flag: true }] },
]

const newItems = items
  .map((item) => ({
    ...item,
    info: item.info.filter((itemInfo) => itemInfo.flag === true),
  }))
  .filter((item) => item.info.length > 0)

console.log(newItems)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `Array.prototype.reduce()`:

```js
let items = [{
    tab: 'tab1',
    info: [{
      mnemonic: 'first',
      value: 'alm',
      flag: true
    }, {
      mnemonic: 'second',
      value: 'jim',
      flag: true
    }]
  },
  {
    tab: 'tab2',
    info: [{
      mnemonic: 'first',
      value: 'kim',
      flag: false
    }, {
      mnemonic: 'second',
      value: 'tim',
      flag: false
    }]
  },
  {
    tab: 'tab3',
    info: [{
        mnemonic: 'first',
        value: 'wint',
        flag: true
      },
      {
        mnemonic: 'second',
        value: 'telt',
        flag: false
      }
    ]
  }
]

const getChecked = () => {
  const res = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (item.info.some(_item => _item.flag)) {
      return [
        ...acc,
        {
          ...item,
          info: item.info.filter(it => it.flag)
        }
      ]
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
  return res;
}
const arr = getChecked();
/*
 * Or you can entirely get rid of the 'getChecked()' function, if you want:
 * 
 * const arr = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
 *   if (item.info.some(_item => _item.flag)) {
 *     return [
 *       ...acc,
 *       {
 *         ...item,
 *         info: item.info.filter(it => it.flag)
 *       }
 *     ]
 *   }
 *   return acc;
 * }, []);
 */
console.log('newArr', arr);
console.log('-items', items);
```